# What is wrong with my System.out.println statements

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have errors with my menu system here are my two classes;
music class( no errors in this):

```
public class music {

  private String title;
  private String artist;
  private int Length;

  public music(String title, String artist, int Length){
   this.artist = artist;
   this.title = title;
   this.Length = Length;
  }

  public String gettitle(){
   return title;
  }

  public String getartist(){
   return artist;
  }

  public int getLength(){
   return Length;
  }
}
```

Music management class:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class musicmanager {

   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   Scanner text = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" ");
   int option =0;

   ArrayList<music>mymusic = new ArrayList<music>();

   System.out.println("Welcome to your music libary");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("1. Add a new song");
   System.out.println("2. Edit a song");
   System.out.println("3.Remove a song");
   System.out.println("4. shuffle your songs")
   System.out.println("5. Exit");
   do{
     System.out.println("please make a choice");
     option = in.nextInt();

     switch(option){
      }

    case 1:


   }
}
```

i have errors with my menu system with the . between out and println, with the text in the brackets and the ; on the end of each system out line of code. eclipse is telling me it is a syntax error but on other projects i have done there is no error.

Comment: In other projects you have done, your `System.out.println` calls were probably within a method, rather than sitting within the Class body itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have lots going wrong in your code here. If you're doing anything other than assignments - both variable declarations or methods - the code must be contained in a method for usability.

All of your System.out.println()'s and your loop must be in a method, such as your `main()` method. An example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to your music libary");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1. Add a new song");
    System.out.println("2. Edit a song");
    System.out.println("3.Remove a song");
    System.out.println("4. shuffle your songs")
    System.out.println("5. Exit");
}
```

A `do-while loop` always contains a `while()` condition.

```
do {
    //do something that's looped
} while(option != 5);
```

A `switch-statement` always has its cases inside its body:

```
switch (option) {
    case 1:
       //do something
}
```

Here you are missing your terminating semi-colon:

```
System.out.println("4. shuffle your songs")
```

That should fix the majority of your problems. I would like to suggest following a tutorial on programming with Java.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting your code, the syntax in the do/switch statement does not make sense at all. Do w/o while, case outside switch...

Your code is like:

```
 do{
 System.out.println("please make a choice");
 option = in.nextInt();

 switch(option){
  }

case 1:

}
```

The syntax should be like:

```
 do {
     //do something...
    switch(option) {
        case 1: 
            //do something
        break;
    }
 } 
 while (expression);
```

Comment: That won't compile. Cases are contained in the switch statement.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I hope the questioner realised this...

Comment: You should post what the correct way of using the switch statement is then.